# How to make a substitution for this integrand?

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral is:
$$\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt[5]{x^2+3}} \mathrm{d}x$$
I am confused of which should be included in the substitution. Please help! Thank you so much!

Comment: I would probably let $u^3=x^2+3$. Then $3u^2\,du=2x\,dx$, and when the smoke clears we are integrating $(3/2)(u^4-3u)$.

Answer (score 4):

Your integral is

$$\int \frac{x \cdot x^2}{\sqrt[5]{x^2+3}}dx$$

So the natural choice is $u=x^2+3$.

Comment: I have thought of u=x^2+3,too. but then I do not know how to express it in the numerator

Comment: HINT: $u=x^2+3$ implies $x^2=u-3$, and $x dx = \frac{du}{2}$.

Comment: oh yea, thanks so much for your help! i really do appreciate it